# C# OrderBy IQueryable<T> with Reflection by Property with attribute named For example "Key"

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, attributes, iqueryable

Is it possible to in C# to OrderBy IQueryable with Reflection to get Property name for ordering by property attribute for example Attribute Name = "Key"?

Comment: Something like this? [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on `IEnumerable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet/233505#233505)

Comment: Could you give an example of what you have already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved with: **System.Linq.Dynamic** [enter link description here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)

```
var keyPropertyName = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties()
    .First(p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(ca => ca.AttributeType.Name == "KeyAttribute")).Name;

return _dbSet.OrderBy(keyPropertyName).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```